# May Not definition?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm playing a forum game and am on the hunt for loopholes. So here's the question: With the following rule in place, do I have the option to use coordinating conjunctions?

```
You may not use any coordinating conjuctions
```

The main question is whether or not 'may not' is a complete prohibition, or if it is simply providing me with the option to not use coordinating conjunctions.

Comment: *No smoking allowed*, *Do not smoke* and *You may not smoke on the premisis* all mean the same thing. May not is not a recommendation, option, or a loophole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a period at the end of that rule, then it is plainly the case that the conjunctions are not allowed.

More specifically, the interpretation is as follows: the rules give you permission to play in a particular manner, however, this rule indicates that you do not have permission to use these conjunctions.

You might be thinking of the common mistake of confusing "can" with "may". "Can I have a cookie" means "am I physically capable of having a cookie". "May I have a cookie" which is more likely what is intended, means "do I have your permission to have a cookie."

Either way, you are out of luck on your loophole.